# Drop down menu not visible at all when using position absolute

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I am creating a drop down menu and I cannot seem to get the sub menu to appear at all when using position: absolute; on the sub-menu (Trying to replicate the bootstrap dropdown menu).

All i'm after is a solution to getting it to display like bootstrap dropdown menu.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you set `overflow: hidden;` on `header`, `.container` and `#header-navigation` elements.

Remove or change its to `visible` and your drop down menu will works well.

Comment: Thanks mate you are a bloody life savor! Thumbs up to you!